# Lower bound for variance of ratio of dependent random variables

Tags: pr.probability, taylor-series

I'm trying to find a lower bound on $\text{Var}(X / Y)$ for **dependent** random variables $X, Y \in [0, 1]$ with $X \leq Y$.
More specifically, $X$ and $Y$ are defined as follows:

Let $h, n \in \mathbb{N}$ be positive integers and $\{Z_k, k \in \mathbb{N}_0\}$ be a strictly stationary time series whose margins are absolutely continuous random variables with support $(0, \infty)$. Then, it holds that
$$
X = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{1}\{X_k > u, X_{k + h} > u\}, 
\quad 
Y = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k = 1}^n \mathbb{1}\{X_k > u\},
$$
where $u > 0$ is some threshold. Furthermore, assume that the correlation between $X$ and $Y$ lies in (-1, 1). Also, we know that the ratio $\mathbb{P}(Z_0 > u, Z_h > u) / \mathbb{P}(X_0 > u)$ converges to some constant in $(0, 1)$.

[Online](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ehseltman/files/ratio.pdf), I found the following approximation for general random variables $X$ and $Y$ with support $(0, \infty)$:

$$
\text{Var}(X / Y) \approx \frac{(\mathbb{E}X)^2}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} \bigg(
\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{(\mathbb{E}X)^2} 
- 
2 \frac{\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y}
+
\frac{\text{Var}(Y)}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} 
\bigg) 
\tag{1}
$$

The underlying proof of this approximation seems to be a Taylor expansion. However, it appears that all remainder terms of the expansion were just removed and equality signs $=$ turned to approximation $\approx$. Is there any justification why the remainder terms are negligible in the variance? This is non-trivial to me.

In terms of my desired lower bound, the RHS of (1) is something I can work with, so I'd like to show something along the lines of
$$
\text{Var}(X / Y) \geq C \frac{(\mathbb{E}X)^2}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} \bigg(
\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{(\mathbb{E}X)^2} 
- 
2 \frac{\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y}
+
\frac{\text{Var}(Y)}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} 
\bigg)
$$
for some constant $C > 0$. I tried proving this using a Taylor expansion which yields

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X / Y) 
&=
\frac{(\mathbb{E}X)^2}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} \bigg(
\frac{\text{Var}(X)}{(\mathbb{E}X)^2} 
- 
2 \frac{\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{\mathbb{E}X\mathbb{E}Y}
+
\frac{\text{Var}(Y)}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} 
\bigg) \\  
&+ \text{Var}(R_1) +
\frac{2}{\mathbb{E}Y} \mathbb{E} \big[(X - \mathbb{E}X) R_1 \big]
-
\frac{2\mathbb{E}X}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} \mathbb{E} \big[(Y - \mathbb{E}Y) R_1 \big],
\end{align}
$$
where $R_1$ is the remainder term
$$
R_1 
= 
\frac{Y - \mathbb{E}Y}{((1 - \theta) \mathbb{E}Y + \theta Y)^2}
\bigg(
  \frac{(1 - \theta) \mathbb{E}X + \theta X}{(1 - \theta) \mathbb{E}Y + \theta Y}
- (X - \mathbb{E}X)
\bigg),
$$
for some $\theta \in [0, 1]$.

Consequently, it would be desirable if one could show that
$$
\text{Var}(R_1) +
\frac{2}{\mathbb{E}Y} \mathbb{E} \big[(X - \mathbb{E}X) R_1 \big]
-
\frac{2\mathbb{E}X}{(\mathbb{E}Y)^2} \mathbb{E} \big[(Y - \mathbb{E}Y) R_1 \big] \geq 0.
$$
(greater than some other non-negative constant would work too.)
I tried showing this using the boundedness of $X$ and $Y$ and their monotonic relationship but so far I failed to make this work.

Any ideas on

1. how to make this proof work? or
2. how to find a lower bound for the variance some other way? or
3. why the remainder terms in (1) were negligible?

Comment: The exact lower bound under your conditions is $0$, attained when $X=Y$.

Comment: Of course Iosif's comment does not preclude the existence of other lower bounds depending on the means, variances and covariance of $X$ and $Y$, that might be $> 0$ when the correlation of $X$ and $Y$ is less than $1$.

Comment: You are both correct, of course. Thank you for your input. I've tried to abstract the problem as much as possible to restrict it to my core question. Turns out, I forgot one important details. In my case $X$ and $Y$ cannot be equal. I've edited the question and specified $X$ and $Y$ accordingly.